# Crystal Reports Viewer gives "Fail to render the page." in a custom Sharepoint webpart when not logged in as admin

Tags: sharepoint-2010, crystal-reports

I've created a custom Sharepoint 2010 webpart with an embedded Crystal Reports Viewer.  It runs fine when I'm logged into Sharepoint as administrator, but it gives "Fail to render page" when logged in as a standard user.  Seems obvious that it's a permissions error, but I don't know how to fix it.  If it affects anything, the assembly version is 13.0.2000.0 in a C# Visual Web Part.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it (mostly)... hopefully this helps someone else.

I downloaded and ran Sysinternal's Process Monitor.  I set the filter to the w3wp.exe process and it quickly turned up lots of access denieds on the user's folder for the user that the app pool runs under.  I granted read/write to the folder and now the report runs.  The images aren't appearing on the report, but I think that's another issue.